# How to perform clicking action under specified child, and parent

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I give the driver an element to match, and the corresponding parent, then I give the driver an element I would like it to click on, under that specified parent.

In the picture I have two highlighted areas. The first of which contains the `title = 'seanthejvr'`. Then the second highlighted area with the `label = "Like"`. They both fall under the main class `"Mr508"`. As you can see there are multiple `"Mr508"` classes, each with a different title. I can only use the title. How do I click on that specific like label for the title `'seanthejvr'`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFU0H.png

```
child = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@title,'{}')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'P9YgZ')]".format(i))

child.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@aria-label='Like']").click()
```

I used `'P9YgZ'` because that's the parent in which both elements fall under. However when I use this code it seems to `"like"` a random set of titles. Rather than the ones I give it.

Comment: Where is _...In the picture I have two highlighted areas..._?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFU0H.png here is the link to the photo. I'd greatly appreciate your help. Thank you for your time.